# CRUD operation in JSP

Tags: jsp

1. How to loop a checkbox when data is
   retrieved from table in a database?
2. How to populate a pop-up window when
       checkboxes are checked in a table to
       update the table?

Comment: The questions are not clear. From 1st question do you mean "How to retrieve data from a db table and display that data as a HTML table? And also show checkbox against each one?

Comment: Hi Pangea, actually retrieved process are over and i also added checkbox and edit link...the question is if i click the checkbox and then click the edit link a new pop up wil be generatedd the pop up will contain selected row of values in a textbox for updating work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give checkboxes value of database id and on clicking on **edit** link check for the id and get the data for that id from database in popup. Now that you have id of raw you can easily update the data.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="db_id" value="<%=db_id_value %>"/>
```

Hope you understand.